# Text goes outside of the card in bootstrap-4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to write some text over image using bootstrap card-img-overlay

I've write this code :

```
<div class="h-100">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <img class="card-img" src="../imgs/header.jpg" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay h-100">
        <div class="container h-75 pt-5">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="my-col h-100">
              <h2 class="card-title text-danger">WEBO DESIGN</h2>
              <p
                class="text-secondary card-text"
              >Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus animi non adipisci iure in, ab perspiciatis, cum ipsum ea, tempore assumenda. Quod molestias cupiditate vitae eius reiciendis expedita quo nulla adipisci totam rerum tempora, minus, unde facilis inventore pariatur asperiores soluta perferendis, dolores repellat natus similique incidunt! Eius, fugiat consequatur.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ans CSS :

```
.my-col {
  width: 50%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

But the text goes outside the card as show in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG1xW.png)

Can anyone help me to fix that and have all the text inside the card ?

Comment: Try removing the all of the `h-100` classes, and use the css property `background-image` to display the image instead of an `img` html tag

Comment: when i use the ```background-image``` the image disappears in small screen devices !!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the class `.my-col { width: 50% }`

I adjusted it for you by specifying a class of `col col-md-8` where 8 can be any width (1-12) you want for medium to larger screens.

This is why: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns

Here's a Pen: https://codepen.io/atlanticdesignagency/pen/jjrVoJ

**Edit:**

Also, if you'd like to make a multi-section card, here's how: https://codepen.io/atlanticdesignagency/pen/orLBwo